# StateMachine flow in a master-detail model

Tags: c#, oracle, database-design, devexpress, xaf

I need to ask a complicated scenario, so I'll try to explain by example.

Consider the following model :

```
public enum States { Created, Approved, Started, Completed }

public class Request {
    States State {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<RequestLine> Lines {get; set;}
}

public class RequestLine {
    States State {get; set;}
    Request Request {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<WorkOrder> WorkOrders {get; set;}
}   

public class WorkOrder {
    States State {get; set;}
    RequestLine RequestLine {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<WorkOrderAction> Actions {get; set;}
}

public class WorkOrderAction {
    States State {get; set;}
    WorkOrder WorkOrder {get; set;}
}
```

So every record has a State, and they're all connected. When a WorkOrderAction is created I have to update WorkOrder state, then RequesTLine state, and then Request state. For every WorkOrderAction record I should check other children records State and update the parent record.

I can do this using database triggers, which I don't prefer. I use Devexpress XAF on application level so I can also code some logic there. But still I can't decide which approach is better.

Is there a common concept for linked state machines?

Answer (score 2):

We only need to know the "other incompleted children".

1. We can enumerate all them: foreach(parent.Children) if(child.State != Completed).However this will load them all so there would be a performance hit
2. We can perform roundtrip to database using something like Execute(new BinaryOperator("State", Completed, NotEquals), AggreagateOperand.Count). This requires restructuring of the domain and the performance hit is less than the previous one.
3. We can update the parent's 'IncompletedChildren' member (integer) when each children is saved/deleted/removed/added. A Parent object is  always loaded so we can determine that the parent is Completed when "IncompletedChildren == 0", mark it as completed and force completion to its parent recursively. There is no additional loading to traffic (one 'integer' is not a "loading" imho). 
   However this approach forces "OptimisticLoading" increment for each 'IncompletedChildren' update - it makes this approach unusable in some scenarios.

I would recommend the 2nd approach.

PS:  In our projects/tasks system we have introduced calculated fields with expressions "Items[State <> Completed].Count. However this cannot work in reality. Most of the times at least in our system the Completed state didn't meant that everything is completed :)

Comment: Apostolis you understood my scenario perfectly, thanx :) 
I'll try the 2nd approach and see if it executes in an acceptable performance.  PS: great work on expand framework, haven't tried it completely but I want to use it with this project :)

Answer (score 0):

The common practice doesn't really have anything to do with state machines. That is, state machines aren't special when it comes to enforcing data integrity rules.

If it has to work right for *all* users, then it makes sense to implement it in triggers. Only code controlled by the dbms can enforce data integrity rules for all users. (And *all users* includes the sleep-deprived DBA and her command-line tools.)

Comment: Hi, I think I couldn't describe the question right, besides data integrity my problem is about performance. When I query Request records where State is Completed, I don't want to query all the child records and decide if it's completed. I need to update the Request state as RequestLines change their State.

Comment: @xarux: You want to update one or more rows in one table when rows in another table change? That's what triggers are for. I can't imagine why you'd need to query intermediate tables to do that. (Unless you re-invented IMS in a SQL dbms.)

Comment: Of course that's what triggers are for, but here I'm talking about an application framework, which is XAF. You see everything on the application model, but when you introduce complex triggers, a team of developers may find it hard to track how an update has occured. So instead of triggers I'm thinking of workflows which can be modified more easily without hardcoding everything.

Comment: 1) A trigger that updates three tables likely fits on one screen. 2) Frameworks and languages come and go; the database is forever. (I've worked on an OLTP system that had programs in more than 25 languages written over the course of more than 30 years.)  3) The need for "easily modified workflows" suggests that your integrity constraints  are either fluid or not well understood. Either one of those is going to be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand the question, but if you're asking about enforcing data integrity "cascading" (a cascading update), then I would consider setting up "deferrable" constraints, which will defer checking the constraint check until a commit is issued.  You'd then do your updates to parent/child as needed and then commit.

Here's a link regarding [deferrable constraints](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm) from Oracle.

Comment: Hi, my question is not about constraints. Think about it this way, you have a 4 level deep model. So when I create 4th level record I have to check it's state because it will affect the upper level's state. A Request's state doesn't change directly, when it's children RequestLine records are all completed, then the Request' state should be completed.

Comment: ok, more clear now.  Still sounds like you need to handle the firing of events in the db (which would mean triggers to update parents or upper level state), or setup deferrable constraints, do the updates in your app, and then commit.  Why have you ruled out triggers all-together? (not a huge fan of complicated trigger systems in db, but still curious)

Comment: I didn't rule out triggers, I'm just trying to find an alternative way. This kind of complex triggers are hard to follow on a big project. BeforeInsert trigger for WorkOrderAction will try to update, WorkOrder, then RequestLine and then Request itself. I'm thinking of a workflow which can handle this.